# How to make pointer show object's string variable?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, scope, undefined-behavior

I made a simple test program because i couldn't figure out why pointers access object's integer values while it couldn't show string variable when objects were created inside another scope.
When i delete these brackets, the pointer returns string's variable normally while with brackets there is just nothing inside this string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int test() {
    cout << "NO ELO MORDECZKI" << endl;
    return 1;
}

class TEST {
public:
    int i;
    int j;
    string a;

    TEST(int i, int j, string a) { this->i = i; this->j = j; this->a=a; }
    
    void operator +(TEST b) {
        this->i = this->i - b.i;
        if (i < 0) {
            cout << b.i << endl;
            b.i -= - (test()*100);
            cout << b.i << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    TEST* l1;
    TEST* l2;

    {
        TEST a{ 1,2, "asd" }, b{ rand() % 20 + 10,1, "asdf" };
        l1 = &a;
        l2 = &b;
    }
    *l1 + *l2;
    cout << "->" << l1->i << "<-" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The life time of the objects `a` and `b` stops after the control exits the compound statement where the objects are defined. So outside the scope the pointers `l1` and `l2` have invalid values.

```
TEST* l1;
TEST* l2;

{
    TEST a{ 1,2, "asd" }, b{ rand() % 20 + 10,1, "asdf" };
    l1 = &a;
    l2 = &b;
} //this ends the scope, which destroys `a` and `b`

*l1 + *l2;
```

For the data member `string a;` there was called its destructor.  As a result the program has undefined behavior.